# Error when setting a variable

Tags: prolog

This is probably a really easy error but I've spent the last 2 hours on it and I just cant get anywhere with it. My code produces `sentence(np(det(a), np2(adj(very), np2(adj(old), np2(noun(woman))))), vp(verb(loves), np(det(a), np2(adj(tricky), np2(noun(crossword)))` and I'm starting to split it by the use of

`split(sentence(np(det(_), np2(A)), VP)) :-
    Write(A).`

for some reason it fails but cant for the life of me find out why. Sorry for the novice question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to match `np2(A)` with `np2(adj(...),np2(...))`

Try

```
split(sentence(np(det(_), np2(A,_)), VP)) :-
  write(A).
```

Comment: Thank you so much, spent way to long trying to sort that

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the novice answer but I only studied a very minimal amount of bprolog in my college days.
I just counted your brackets and there appears to be three missing closing braces at the very end to close the np2(adj, vp( and the sentence(.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I cant seem to get it working when changing the brackets